# Batch: Run through directory recursively

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I recursively traverse a directory structure in a Windows batch file?

I did not find any examples on Internet, except one where the author lists all directories in a text file and then reads the text file and enter into directory and repeats.

Comment: What operating system and what shell? :-)

Comment: What about `dir /s /b`

Answer (score 1):

Check out `FOR /R` loops.

> FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

```
Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
will just enumerate the directory tree.
```

An example:

```
C:\>md dummy
C:\>cd dummy
C:\dummy>md foo
C:\dummy>md foo\bar
C:\dummy>for /r %i in (.);do @echo %i
```

givs output:

```
C:\dummy\.
C:\dummy\foo\.
C:\dummy\foo\bar\.
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats a good example :-)